# Is my proof for $\lim_{x\to 0} {cos{1\over x}}$ does not exist correct?

Tags: proof-verification, epsilon-delta

I decided to try proof by contradiction since the negation of the definition of a limit is $\exists \epsilon > 0 \space \forall \delta > 0 \space , 0 < |x - c| < \delta \land |f(x) - L| \geq \epsilon$

Suppose $\lim_{x\to 0} {cos{1\over x}}$ exists, and let its limit be equal to L. Let $\epsilon = {L\over2}$. Let |x|  = $1\over{n\pi\over2}$ for some odd n $\in N$, and let n be sufficently small such that ${1\over{n\pi\over2}} < \delta$. Then, $f(x) = cos({1\over{1\over{n\pi\over2}}}) = 0$. Therfore, |f(x) - L| = |0 - L| = |L| > $L\over2$ > $\epsilon$. Hence, the limit does not exist.

Comment: What's $L$?  The supposed limit?   Where in your argument do you show that $L=0$ doesn't work?  For that matter, what if $L<0$?

Comment: @lulu L is supposed to be the supposed limit sorry. Why will I have to show that L = 0 doesn't work?

Comment: because if $L=0$ then $L>\frac{L}{2}$ is false

Comment: Well, a priori $0$ is a possible limit.  I think you have successfully shown that no $L>0$ could be a limit.  To do that, you argued (correctly) that there is a sequence of values, $x_n=\frac 2{n\pi}$ such that  $x_n\to 0$ and $\cos   (\frac 1{x_n})=0$.  Good!  But you still have to show that $L≤0$ is also impossible.  (Hint:  your argument also rules out $L<0$ if you are more careful.  So all you have to worry about is $L=0$.

Comment: @lulu Quick question, if L < 0, the |0 - L|= L right? So why is L < 0 still a problem?

Comment: Well, first of all, for $L<0$ we have $|0-L|=-L$ (absolute values can never be $<0$).  Secondly, your inequality $L>\frac L2$ is false if $L<0$, third it doesn't make sense to define $\epsilon = \frac L2$ if $L<0$.

Comment: Like I say, though, you can repair your argument so that it works for $L<0$.  You just need to be more careful.  That will just leave $L=0$ which really can't be handled by your argument.

Comment: @lulu can I state that $0<L\le1$. If that repairs L < 0, to repair L = 0, can't I just state that $L \ge L/2$? or should I say $|L| \le {L\over2}$

Comment: You've lost me.  You have already handled the case $L>0$, nothing more to do there.  You still have to handle the case $L<0$ (I am telling you that this is relatively easy, given what you have already done, but you still have to do it).  And you can't take $L=0$ in your argument as it makes no sense to define $\epsilon =0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)=\cos(1/x)$ and $x_n = \frac{1}{n \pi}$ for $n \in \mathbb N$ then $x_n \to 0$ but

$$f(x_n)=(-1)^n.$$

Conclusion ?